# Reading from CSV and assigning to variables

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, csv

I have a pandas DataFrame constructed from a CSV. A column in it has values of different data types.

for example:

```
data =
      val
key
0      6
1      y
2     1.0
```

I used

```
a, b, c = pd.data.val.tolist()
```

It treats every value as string.

How do I read 6 as int y as str and 1.0 as float?

Comment: is the datatype on the column set correctly?

Comment: What do you mean? I think it is. In the CSV, the values are 6, y, 1.0.

Comment: csv dont have datatypes. When you change it to a df, are the types correct?

Comment: I think yes. If I print the DataFrame, the above output is shown. Doesn't that mean it is correct?

Comment: df.info() should tell you that

Comment: It says object. Should the values be parsed when creating the dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.to_numeric` and then `combine_first`:

```
pd.to_numeric(data['val'],errors='coerce').combine_first(data['val']).values.tolist()
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.  
My understanding of this from reading the documentation is that it takes the `val` column and replaces the non numeric values with `NaN` and replaces the `Nan`s with non numeric values from `val`, then it converts those values to a list. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Can `int`s be read as `int`? It is by default reading all numbers as float.

Comment: @Shreshta yes, you are right in your first comment, but second one is possible if all values in column are int